# How to solve spoj Dquery with one more constraint

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, distinct-values

I have solved this spoj  [DQUERY](http://www.spoj.com/problems/DQUERY/)
problem using MO's Algorithms in time complexity of `N*Sqrt(N)`.
 But, now I want one more constraint on each query, that is,now each query contains the four integers `i,j,x,y`such as:

```
(1 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ n)
(1 ≤ x ≤ y ≤ 10^6)
```

For each d-query (i, j), you have to return the number of distinct elements in the subsequence ai, ai+1, ..., aj  which is greater or equal to `x` and less or equal to `y`.
**For example:**
If `n=5` arrays element be

```
1 1 2 1 3
```

then, for query (i,j,x,y):

```
1 5 2 3
```

answer will be:

```
2
```

because, in range from `i=1` to `j=5` three distinct element`{1,2,3}` is present but only two element`{2,3}` is present in range `x=2` to `y=3`.So anwer is `2`.
I am getting solution in time complexity of **(Q*Sqrt(N)*X)***, please help how to solve this question with **efficient time  complexity** less than **(QSqrt(N)*X)**.